# How do I install the nltk data sets using a custom cacert pem?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, nltk, pem

I am behind an obnoxious mitm ssl proxy and when I try to install the nltk data, I get this:

```
[usr01@site04 ~]$ python
import nltk
nltk.download()

NLTK Downloader
d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
Downloader> l

Packages:
Error connecting to server: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
Downloader>
```

For the nltk package itself, I can hand it a corporate certificate bundle pem file and succeed, like this:

```
pip install --cert=/home/usr01/cacert.pem --user -U nltk
```

So what I believe I need is a way to pass in a cacert file to the nltk downloader somehow, but I can't seem to make any headway finding out the syntax for doing this, or if it is even possible.  I do not have an https proxy, so the examples I have seen regarding nltk.set_proxy() won't work.

As a stop-gap, I just worked around the downloader by grabbing the zip from https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/tree/gh-pages and then unzipping it, but when these sets are updated I will be left manually curating them, not to mention that I have to copy corpora and the other parts in the repo around manually.

So, is there a way to hand the nltk.download() mechanism a pem file?

Comment: You might need to handle the certificates before `nltk.download()`. Maybe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests will help. Just curious, why are you behind an mitmproxy (usually use for pentesting)?  That sounds crazy...

Comment: Maybe something like http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.4/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: you could write a script to download and unzip in Python

Comment: Thanks for the doc alvas, and to answer your question, my work insists on using it.

Comment: I will look more into changing it at the python level. Under the covers, the Downloader.py uses compat.urlopen(), which is an alias for urllib2.urlopen(), which does take a cafile argument.  I tried hacking that to hard code the cafile but could not get it to work either.

Comment: What is the SSL Errorno. you've got? Maybe that will help us help you debug the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems to be swallowed up somewhere in the layers of indirection from urllib2 which I'm guessing calls openssl libraries under the covers somewhere.